# how to fix the method calling function with passing an two argument

Tags: java

I am creating a todo-list with a login page in which I have a two-input table as name, things in which name, things are not sending data to server

this is Repository...

```
public interface TodosRepository extends CrudRepository<Todos, Long> {

    Todos findByName(String name,String things);

    List<Todos> findByCompletedAndUserId(boolean complated, Long Id);

}
```

this is my entity

```
@Entity
public class Todos {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String things;
    private String name;
    private boolean completed;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Todos() {
    }

    public Todos(String name,String things, boolean completed) {
        this.things = things;
        this.name = name;
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public String getThings() {
        return things;
    }

    public void setThings(String things) {
        this.things = things;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Todos [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ",things=" + things +", completed=" + completed + "]";
    }

}
```

java.util.NoSuchElementException: null

Comment: which query is giving you error. also please share the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think spelling is wrong thats why ,`completed` not `complated` 
`List<Todos> findByCompletedAndUserId(boolean complated, Long Id);`
The parameters names should be same as per Method-name. like method name has `userId` whereas arguments has only `id`

Answer (score 0):

you don't have this Annotation try with this line under `@Entity`

```
@Table(name = "your-table")
```

Comment: Hii, thank you for your comments .but, I am getting an SQL syntax error